# Error in counting country records and not including countries?

Tags: php, mysqli

From the following query, I want to count all the countries that are registered through a reference code, which I have called coderegister, except the country of the United States.

```
$Not_Us_code = "US";
$Not_Us_name = "United States";
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? NOT IN (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$coderegister,$Not_Us_code,$Not_Us_name);
$stmt->execute();
$counted = null;
$stmt->bind_result($counted);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close()
```

The problem here is that it shows me 0 result, when there are records.

Now in the same way I do the count of the countries registered by means of a reference code this time it should be counted only the country of the United States

```
$country_code = "US";
$country_name = "United States";
$stmt1=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? AND country_code=? OR country_name=?");
$stmt1->bind_param("sss",$coderegister,$country_code,$country_name);
$stmt1->execute();
$counted_1 = null;
$stmt1->bind_result($counted_1);
$stmt1->fetch();
$stmt1->close();
```

The problem here is that it tells me all the records and does not respect the reference code, that is, if there are 100 records with different reference code, this query shows me 100 records that should not happen, if there are only 10 records using that code of reference you should only show me the 10 records.

---

Code of reference is `coderegister -> AC1234`

Comment: According to me,this query has not sense

     `$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? NOT IN (?,?)");`

I think you must specify a field before the IN operator
eg: 

 

   `$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE country_name  NOT IN  (?,?)");`

Comment: in the second case i think your last Or could be responsible.Test the query without the OR a let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the field names used in your second query, your first query should probably look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? AND country_code!=? AND country_name!=?
```

and your second query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? AND (country_code=? OR country_name=?)
```

Your current first query has syntax errors (you are not checking for a field to be `NOT IN`, and your second query has an operator precedence problem (`AND` happens before `OR`).

**Edit**

If country_code and country_name can be `NULL` and you want those entries to be returned by the first query, you should change it to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM country WHERE coderegister=? AND
  (country_code != ? OR country_code IS NULL) AND 
  (country_name != ? OR country_name IS NULL)
```

Comment: The problems of the first consultation are solved with the code of answer

Comment: However I do not understand the first query, what you have specified works the same as (NOT IN), because in the first consultation all countries except the United States are counted

Comment: The first query finds all countries whose country_code is not 'US' AND whose country_name is not 'United States' that match the coderegister value. It has a similar effect as a NOT IN clause. I think that is what you wanted? A x NOT IN (a,b) clause is like saying x is not a and x is not b i.e. x!=a and x!=b. However because you have two different variables country_code and country_name it is necessary to use the form that I did rather than a NOT IN clause

Comment: but there is an error, it does not tell me the null records, that is, they do not have data in country_code and country_name that query must be global to count all the records except the country US.

Comment: Hi Ronaldo I've added an edit that will allow the first query to return entries where `country_code` or `country_name` are `NULL`